# Data Integration Tool For HANA

Tags: hana, data-integration

Is there a good data integration tool available for SAP HANA which could accomplish the following :

1. Consuming data periodically (a user defined interval) from REST based web service (A simple URL containing XML)
2. Parsing the XML and extracting the data
3. Populating the associated table

I am aware that SQL Server Integration Service is one such tool available for Microsoft SQL Server, which does the above. Would like to know the equivalent in HANA. I did explore SAP Cloud Integration service and Business Object Data Services tool, but would like to have a first hand opinion on the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAP HANA Smart Data Integration (SDI) is a standard product option that you can use for this. As it is a feature of SAP HANA, no additional server is required for this solution. This blog gives a good overview [SAP SDI BLOG](https://blogs.saphana.com/2015/09/11/simplifying-sap-hana-data-integration-landscape/).

Data Services can of course also used for that, but would probably be the 'Ferrari for driving to the bakery'.

Comment: SDI requires a DP Agent- an extra Server. The recommendation from the EIM SDI Admin Guide is to install the DP Agent on a separate server/VM.

Comment: So? Of course, when the data capturing and transformation workload gets high, additional resources are required. In this context it's worth mentioning that there is no need for additional HANA certified hardware as the DP agents can run on cheap systems.